# standard deviation on different columns with a regular step in a dataframe

Tags: r

I've a problem calculating SD on my data frame in R. I need to calculate SD on each column with a `step=3`. So SD on km `1:3`, SD on km `4:6`, ...

I have already tried different solutions but unfortunately without success:

```
df <- data.frame(km = c(1:13),
A2012 = c(0.1,0.3,0.8,0.45,0.98,0.45,0.75,0.71,0.36,0.11,0.26,0.68,0.41), 
A2013 = c(0.36,0.11,0.26,0.68,0.41,0.45,0.1,0.3,0.8,0.98,0.45,0.75,0.71))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By cutting the dataframe in ranges and then splitting this is achievable:

```
df$ranges <- cut(df$km,seq(1,13,3),include.lowest=T,right=F)
###new solution, much nicer
SDs <- aggregate(df[,2:3],list(df$ranges),sd)

### old solution
SDs <- t(sapply(split(df,df$ranges),function(df){
  apply(df[,2:3],2,sd)
}))

###solution to question in comment:

cuts <- matrix(data=c(seq(1,max(df$km)-3,2),seq(4,max(df$km),2)),ncol=2)
SDs <- t(sapply(1:nrow(cuts),function(rn)
{
  SD <- apply(subset(df,df$km >= cuts[rn,1] & df$km <= cuts[rn,2])[,2:3],2,sd)
  return(SD)
}))
rownames(SDs) <- apply(cuts,1,paste,collapse = "-")
colnames(SDs) <- paste0("sd(",colnames(SDs),")")
SDs
     sd(A2012) sd(A2013)
1-4  0.2954516 0.2412986
3-6  0.2644491 0.1737815
5-8  0.2171597 0.1567376
7-10 0.3039051 0.4132392
9-12 0.2412986 0.2200757
```

Comment: I've edited in a nicer solution. My old solution works the same, but is less concise.

Comment: It is possible to make a sliding windows SD ? So for example, to make an SD of KM 1:4 then to make an SD on KM 2:6 for the second, etc..

Comment: Yes in principle that is possible. Just to check, is your window size supposed to change? Because `1:4`is smaller than `2:6`

Comment: It's my fault, sorry. it's not a windows 2:6 but 3:6

Comment: It's perfect ! i tried to use "endpoints" and "rolling_sd" functions, but they are specific at time windows. Thank you very much Julian.